# How to add a native C++ dll in a Windows Form C++.NET project in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a native C++ project. It can produce either a dll or lib file.

I am creating a C++.NET project (C++ Windows Form application) in Visual Studio 2010. I Would like to add that library into this project in order to call public methods from that library.

I have three questions:

1. Should I produce a dll or lib file from the native C++ Project?
2. How can I add that native library in the C++.NET project?
3. I am looking for sample code to show how to call a method from the native library in the C++.NET project.

I am very new to C++.NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/usingcppdll.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Specify the DLL to load from with: `DllImport("user32.dll"...`,  set  `EntryPoint = "my_unmanaged_function"` to import your desired unmanaged function to your shiny new Managed C++ app:

```
#using <mscorlib.dll>
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices; 
// for DllImportAttribute

namespace SysWin32
{
   [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "MessageBox", CharSet = Unicode)]
   int MessageBox(void* hWnd, wchar_t* lpText, wchar_t* lpCaption, 
                  unsigned int uType);
}

int main( )
{
   SysWin32::MessageBox( 0, L"Hello world!", L"Greetings", 0 );
}
```

Source and even more `DllImport` examples : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984739(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: is there any way that I dont use the dllImport way? is there any way just like adding header files? then I need to compile the native C++ library in a lib file and copy the header files to the Visual C++.NET project. Is that correct?